# Ansible loop to add member in Azure AD group using graph api

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have been stuck to loop over each "members" in variable file. Reason to take each members is to get user_id and passing those user id in graph api will be able to POST those members in specific AD group.

main.yml

```
- name: Check if Group Exists
  include_tasks: tasks/groups/check_group.yml

- name: Create Group
  include_tasks: tasks/groups/create_group.yml
  when: item.state == "present" and az_group_id == ""

- name: Populate the group with members
  include_tasks: tasks/groups/add_member.yml
  when: az_group_id != "" and item.state == "present"
  loop: "{{ az_group_config_data }}"
```

add_member.yml

```
- name: Get Azure AD User ID
  include_tasks: tasks/users/gets/get_user_id.yml

- name: Add Member to a group
  uri:
    url: "{{ graph_api_base_url }}{{ group_service_context }}/{{ az_group_id }}/members/$ref"
    method: POST
    body: "{{ lookup('template','./add-group-member-body.j2') }}"
    status_code: 204
    return_content: yes
    use_proxy: no
    headers:
      Authorization: Bearer {{ token }}
    body_format: json
  register: group_create_result
```

get_userid.yml

```
- name: Register list of Azure Users as Ansible Fact
  uri:
    url: "{{ graph_api_base_url }}{{ user_service_context }}?$top=999&$select=mail,id"
    method: GET
    status_code: 200
    use_proxy: no
    headers:
      Authorization: Bearer {{ token }}
  register: user_list_result
  

- name: Register User {{ az_user_mail }} ID as Ansible Fact
  set_fact:
    az_user_id: "{{ user_list_result.json.value | json_query(az_user_id_query) }}"
```

defaults/main.yml

```
 az_group_config_data:

  - az_group_name: ghe-test-users
    aws_account: sbx
    environment: poc
    state: present
    members:
     - name@name.com
     - name@example.com
     - test@test.com
```

vars/main.yml

```
az_group_name: "{{ item.az_group_name }}"
az_user_mail: "{{ item.members }}"

# api helpers
graph_api_base_url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/"
group_service_context: "groups"
user_service_context: "users"

# query helpers
az_group_id_query: "[?displayName == '{{ az_group_name }}'].id | [0]"
az_user_id_query: "[?mail == '{{ az_user_mail }}'].id | [0]"
```

add-group-member-body.j2

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{{ az_user_id }}"
}
```

Below code works to fetch email accounts

```
- name: latest-debug
  set_fact:
    az_user_mail: "{{ populate.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ az_group_config_data|subelements('members') }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: populate
```

My issue is only last email account is getting created.

Comment: What is your actual question? Or what do you need help with?

Comment: @Danstan My bad. I updated the question. last value of the members is getting created, all other values are ignored. How to solve this issue?